# Can't extract actual data from .dat files in C++?

Tags: python, c++

I'm trying to extract data from .dat (data in file is in 16 bit) file in c++ which is showing garbage data. I'm able to extract it in python (code provided below as well) but my work requires it to be in C++. Here is the C code that I'm using.
[image: Image shows junk values on output console]
[image: Second image shows the actual data I was able to extract in python.]
Also I would like to know what is the fastest way to extract data since my file are a bit large in size.

```
#include<iostream>
#define N 4000
using namespace std;
struct record {
char details[1500];
};
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("mirror.dat","rb");
    record *records;
    if (fp==NULL){
    cout<<"Problem \n";
    system("pause");
    return -1;
    }
    records = new record[N];
    fread((record *)records, sizeof(record),N,fp );
    fclose(fp);
    for(int i=0; i<N;i++){
        cout<<"[" << i+1 << "]" << records[i].details << "\n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Below is the python code.

```
fpath="mirror.dat"
with open(fpath, 'rb') as r_file:
            data=r_file.read()
            bits=[data[i+1]<<8 | data[i] for i in range(0, len(data),2)]
            print(type(bits))
            bits_decod = []
            for k in bits:
                bits_decod.append(k)
print((bits_decod))
```

Comment: Why are you using `stdio` in C++?

Comment: If it's a binary file, why are you trying to print it as a text string?

Comment: You should be testing the return values of the various function calls, and your sample C++ output doesn't match your source code - are they back to front? Your Python seems to print integer values. What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: If the file contains 16-bit integers, why not use an array of 16-bit integers?

Comment: Those two programs don't do even remotely the same thing.  The C++ program attempts to read an array of 4000 1500-character arrays while the python program reads a single list of 2-byte integers.

Comment: Please also take the [tour] and read [ask]. Concerning your question, the use of pictures instead of text is also not helpful, and you could also reduce the amount of data to get closer to a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In C++, when you print a `char` array using `<<`, it expects it to be a C-style character string.

You need to write a loop that decodes it similarly to the way the Python script does.

```
#include<iostream>
#define N 4000
using namespace std;
uint8_t data[N * 1500];
uint16_t bits[N * 750];
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    FILE *fp = fopen("mirror.dat","rb");
    record *records;
    if (fp==NULL){
        cout<<"Problem \n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    size_t data_len = fread((void *)data, sizeof(data),1,fp );
    if (data_len < 0) {
        cout << "Read error\n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }
    fclose(fp);
    for (int i = 0; i < data_len; i+=2) {
        bits[i/2] = data[i+1] << 8 | data[i];
    }
    int bits_len = data_len / 2;
    for(int i=0; i<bits_len;i++){
        cout<<"[" << i+1 << "]" << bits[i] << "\n";
    }
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In C++ you can read the contents of a file into a `std::vector` of `uint8_t` with the use of `std::istream_iterator`. Then loop through the vector, decoding the bytes and putting into a vector of `uint16_t`.

`std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(testFile)` is an iterator to beginning of file and `std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>()` is default-constructed with the special state "end-of-stream". So using this iterator can be used to read from the beginning of the file to the end. We don't have to calculate the size ourselves, and therefore can be used to read varying number of entries in the file.

The equivalent C++ program will look something like this:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstddef>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdint>

int main()
{
    //Open file
    std::ifstream testFile("mirror.dat", std::ios::in | std::ios::binary);
    if (!testFile)
    {
        std::cout << "Problem \n";
        system("pause");
        return 1;
    }

    //Read in file contents
    std::vector<uint8_t> data((std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>(testFile)), std::istream_iterator<uint8_t>());
    std::vector<uint16_t> bytes_decoded;
    bytes_decoded.reserve(data.size() / 2);

    //Decode bytes
    for (std::size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); i += 2)
    {
        bytes_decoded.push_back(data[i + 1] << 8 | data[i]);
    }

    //Copy decoded bytes to screen with one space between each number
    std::copy(bytes_decoded.cbegin(), bytes_decoded.cend(), std::ostream_iterator<uint16_t>(std::cout), " ");
    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

Note: This requires C++11 or above for the types `uint8_t` and `uint16_t` in  the header `cstdint`. You could use `unsigned char` and `unsigned short` instead  if you don't have a modern C++ compiler.

Comment: since I have multiple files and the number of entries is unknown, would for loop work in this case if so please elaborate a bit. From what you explained i,m able to extract first entry but for the rest of the file how can I read data if the number of entries is unknown everytime.